# CocoaPods for both iOS and OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, podspec

I have a static library that I've created for iOS 8 and have created a corresponding pod spec file so it can be delivered via CocoaPods.  I'd also like to build and distribute this library on OS X, as well.  Is this possible?  How do I need to setup the project structure and the pod spec file(s)?  Do I need to do anything special?

Comment: Is your project already hosted online in a public git repository or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** it's possible. See the [multi-platform support documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#group_multi_platform_support). Basically you use `spec.ios` and `spec.osx` to specify platform-specific attributes  - e.g. `spec.ios.resources` instead of `spec.resources` to specify iOS-specific resources. [AFNetworking's podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/AFNetworking/2.4.1/AFNetworking.podspec.json) is a good example to have a look at.